# SQLite INSERTAR Y MOSTAR en ListView y CardView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, cardview

Hola amigos soy nuevo he estado siguiendo un video pero al momento de color las lineas para mostrar mis base datos no hace nada.

- YA HE PODIDO AGREGAR EXITOSAMENTE
- NO FUNCIONA LA METODO mostrarArtistas DE LA CLASE DeveloperBD
- EL CUAL ES INSTANCIADO EN LA CLASE MainActivity PARA MOSTRAR EN LA LISTA

me pudieran asesorar con el codigo anexo el codigo en donde creo que esta el error ya que para insertar use CONTENTVALUES Y PARA MOSTRAR ESTOY USANDO SQLiteDatabase AL FINAL ANEXO MI CODIGO GITHUB Y LOS DOS VIDEOS QUE USE

```
public void insert_artista(String n_cancion, String n_artista, String genero, String letra, String nota){
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("NAME_CANCION", n_cancion);
        contentValues.put("NAME_ARTISTA", n_artista);
        contentValues.put("NAME_GERO",genero);
        contentValues.put("NAME_LETRA",letra);
        contentValues.put("NAME_NOTA",nota);
this.getWritableDatabase().insertOrThrow("ARTISTA","",contentValues);}

    public List<CantanteDatos> mostrarArtistas(){
        SQLiteDatabase bd=getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = bd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM ARTISTA",null);
        List<CantanteDatos> cursos = new ArrayList<>();
        if (cursor.moveToNext()){
            do {
                cursos.add(new CantanteDatos(cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4)));
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return cursos;
    }
```

> https://github.com/Austin52/prb_Artista
>   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KtWgbmEe_x4&t=2s
>   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T0ClYrJukPA

[PROYECTO ANDROID STUDIO](https://github.com/Austin52/prb_Artista)

Answer (score 0):

En el Adapter estas retornando null en lugar de una vista (viewHolder). Se corrige así:

```
 public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.itme_nota,viewGroup,false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
   }
```

Comment: Hola es como lo tengo pero sigo sin poder mostrar los datos

Comment: en el archivo que tienes en GitHub tienes return null; en lugar  de return viewHolder;

Comment: En qué clase para corregirlo

Comment: RecyclerViewAdaptador

Comment: Soy nuevo en esto del desarrollo me podrías orientar cómo corregir este error

Comment: revisa la respuesta que di arriba